# How to rate the relevance of a sentence to another body of text

Tags: machine-learning, natural-language

I've got a data/ML problem which I'm not sure how to solve:

I've got a list of n sentences and one longer piece of text. I want to be able to tell which of the n sentences is the most relevant to the longer piece (or get some number that tells me the "relevance score" of each of the n sentences). Does anyone know a good approach for this, or the name of a class of models that might be suitable for this sort of problem?

Comment: Start with jaccard similarity as a baseline model

Comment: Thanks, that's really helpful because now I know what to google for! If you write that as an answer I'll accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with jaccard similarity as a baseline model.